# Remove "essential_grid" from url

Tags: php, wordpress

Now I am working on a wordpress theme. 
I am using themepunch's ***essential grid*** plugin. 
When I see post page, url is showing with "essential_grid" 
That is,  ***example.com/essential_grid/postname*** 
I want to add ***"portfolio"*** instead of **"essential_grid"** 
I am looking for :
***example.com/portfolio/postname*** 
If not Possible, 
***example.com/postname*** 
(please post any htaccess, Jquery, Javascript ..... tricks) 
Please help me. 
Thanks ..

Comment: var str="http://www.example.com/essential_grid/postname"; str.replace("essential_grid", "portfolio");

Answer (score 0):

To use Essential grid in example.com/postname

> Just create page with name postname and eneter shortcode of essential
>   grid inside content or you can create a custom template assign to
>   postname page and then use shortcode of essential grid as you
>   required.

To use Essential Grid in example.com/portfolio/postname

As I can look from url that postname is post of post-type portfolio. For this you have to:

> Just create a custom page with name single-portfolio.php and entered
>   shortcode in it.

From both two methods essential_grid will be removed from url